# Trouble implementing a Slide Show from an ArrayList of Bitmap

Tags: android, multithreading, slideshow

I'm trying to implement a slide show for my App and I seem to be getting stuck on what seems like a small detail.

I'm new to Android and haven't been programming long so I'm not great with threading yet.

Anyways I have an ArrayList which is great. When I try to loop through the ArrayList replacing the images in my ImageView with images in the ArrayList however, I only end up seeing the final image in the List.

I can see in my LogCat that the images are being set (at least that section of the code is running. It is sleeping as I asked (I can notice the 1000ms in the LogCat entries.

I'm doing this in an AsyncTask and trying to set the results from the onPostExecute(). Here is that code...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_show);
    screenSize = MediaHelper.getScreenSize(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Long projectId;
    imageList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ivSlide = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_slide);
    tvLoading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_loading);
    tvLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if(extras != null){
        projectId = extras.getLong("projectId");
        new GetImagesTask().execute(projectId);
    }           
}

class GetImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, ArrayList<Bitmap>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(Long... id) {
        long projectId = id[0];
        Project project = getProject(projectId);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> i = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();      
        File[] files = MediaHelper.getProjectFilenames(project.getImagePath());
        if(files != null && files.length > 0){
            for(File aFile : files){
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaHelper.getScaledImage(aFile, screenSize.y / 2, screenSize.x / 2);
                i.add(bitmap);
                Log.d(TAG, "image added...size = " + bitmap.getByteCount());
            }

        }
        return i;                   
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> result) {
        if(result != null && result.size() > 0){
            imageList = result; 
            if(imageList.size() > 0){
                ivSlide.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        try{
                            for(Bitmap bm : imageList){
                                ivSlide.setImageBitmap(bm);
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Setting ImageView image");
                            }
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted unexpectedly.");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Use ListView or Image Gallery...

Comment: what is your ivSlide?

Comment: Oh Sorry the ivSlide is an ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used *View.post(Runnable)* before so I'm not sure about its behaviour but if it's not running on the UI Thread that *"setImageBitmap"* is not applied instantly, I think it's only applied when some other thread asks your view to reload its layout.

If it runs on the UI Thread, the *Thread.sleep(1000)* is asking the UI to stop working for a whole second, making the *setImageBitmap* effect impossible to notice to the user.

While facing a similar problem some time ago I used a Thread with a while in it that calls to `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` each time it needed to swipe the pictures. That way, the loading task was ran on the UI Thread and the waiting on a background one.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

Could you try replacing your AsyncTask with this one, as suggested on my comment?  gist.github.com/Arasthel/9788601

Comment: I think it could also be done with an AsyncTask, using a while loop and **onProgressUpdate** method to load the Bitmap.

Comment: Could you replace your AsyncTask with the one in this gist? https://gist.github.com/Arasthel/9788601

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely `Thread.sleep()`. This will sleep the main thread and likely prevent the ui from updating till the last image when you don't sleep the thread.

Use `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)` instead of sleeping the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously only the last item will be updated, Because you are running the loop and updating the same variable "ivSlide". For each iteration the same variable is getting updated with the different Bitmap at last it stops with the last Bitmap updated.
  To overcome this you have to update each ivslide view variable with the arraylist index.

Please update full code so I can answer better.

Comment: @Arasthel So I've updated the code to get a better look at what I'm trying to do. It seems to make sense that I would load all the images in an ArrayList then iterate through that List replacing the images in the ImageView. So how do I get it to change the image, redraw the UI, wait 1 second and repeat without tying up the UI thread